# Searching for elegant if

Tags: javascript

Is there more elegant way for this if?

```
   if (err.code === 'CONFLICT-GROUP-GENERAL' ||
    err.code === 'CONFLICT-USER-GENERAL' ||
    err.code === 'CONFLICT-FORM-GENERAL' ||
    err.code === 'CONFLICT-PROJECT-GENERAL' ||
    err.code === 'CONFLICT-TEMPLATE-GENERAL') {}
```

Comment: The correct solution depends a bit on what's between the `{}`.

Comment: I'd use a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This trick seems to me more elegant (using an array and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)):

```
var conflicts = ['CONFLICT-GROUP-GENERAL',
                    'CONFLICT-USER-GENERAL',
                    'CONFLICT-FORM-GENERAL',
                    'CONFLICT-PROJECT-GENERAL',
                    'CONFLICT-TEMPLATE-GENERAL'];

if (conflicts.indexOf(err.code) !== -1) {
    doSomething();   
}
```

If you are using ES7 then you can use [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead of `indexOf`. This will be more "expressive":

```
var conflicts = ['CONFLICT-GROUP-GENERAL',
                    'CONFLICT-USER-GENERAL',
                    'CONFLICT-FORM-GENERAL',
                    'CONFLICT-PROJECT-GENERAL',
                    'CONFLICT-TEMPLATE-GENERAL'];

if (conflicts.inclues(err.code)) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Note that `includes()` will not be suported by all browsers.

**EDIT:**

Another alternative: Using a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). This way:

```
switch (err.code) {
    case 'CONFLICT-GROUP-GENERAL',:
    case 'CONFLICT-USER-GENERAL',:
    case 'CONFLICT-FORM-GENERAL',:
    case 'CONFLICT-PROJECT-GENERAL',:
    case 'CONFLICT-TEMPLATE-GENERAL':
        doSomething();
        break;
}
```

The code above will execute the `doSomething()` function when `err.code` is equal to one of specified strings in each `case`.

Answer (score 6):

I would be better off with an array with all the codes and use `indexOf` to check if it's greater than `-1`:

```
if (['CONFLICT-GROUP-GENERAL', 'CONFLICT-USER-GENERAL', 'CONFLICT-FORM-GENERAL', 'CONFLICT-PROJECT-GENERAL', 'CONFLICT-TEMPLATE-GENERAL'].indexOf(err.code) > -1) {
}
```

Comment: or `includes()`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Isn't that unsupported in old browsers?

Comment: anyways for new browsers ;)